# powershell writing data to COM port remove newline

Tags: powershell, serial-port

I need to send data to a COM port but with out the carriage return.
This is what I have so far;

```
    $port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
    $port.PortName = "COM10"
    $port.BaudRate = 9600
    $port.Parity = "none"
    $port.DataBits = 8
    $port.StopBits = "None"
    $port.Handshake = "None"
    $port.Open()
    $data = $port.ReadExisting()
    if ($data)
    {
        $port.writeLine("OK")
        ...
        ...
    }
```

The problem I have is $port.writeLine("OK") buts a carriage return and I think a space before the OK.
I have a device listening for the OK string put it never gets it.

Is there any way to remove this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `Write()` instead of `WriteLine()`; the former does not include the newline, the latter does. See [the MSDN page on System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) for a full list of properties and methods.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed that.